# Remote Metastore db doesn't share the global_temp database between different spark applications

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

I start a first spark application configured to connect to a remote Hive Metastore DB, through:

```
.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
.set("spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession", "true")
```

Here is the source code:

```
val df = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("json")
      .load("gs://path/location/to/data/")

    df.writeStream.queryName("dictionary")
      .format("memory")
      .start()
```

It seems loading data into "global_temp" database, within the same metastore db instance, as found on logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/hive/hive-metastore.out
    2019-02-04T14:16:51,628 INFO [pool-11-thread-78] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 76: source:10.132.0.67 get_functions: db=default pat=*
    2019-02-04T14:16:51,677 INFO [pool-11-thread-78] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 76: source:10.132.0.67 get_database: default
    2019-02-04T14:16:51,682 INFO [pool-11-thread-78] org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 76: source:10.132.0.67 get_database: global_temp
```

However, when I connect into the Metastore DB through beeline, I never see the dictionary table, or global_temp database. How it is possible ?

I've tried to update the default database value into "dictionaries" database, and create it before running the Job, I get this error message :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   dictionaries is a system preserved database, please rename your
>   existing database to resolve the name conflict, or set a different
>   value for spark.sql.globalTempDatabase, and launch your Spark
>   application again.

Any idea why the table "dictionary" never appear on the metastore db ?

Comment: global_temp is reserved database for global views, as shown in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html